# Convert pandas dateframe from row to column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

| ID | value | freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 0.1 |
| A | b | 0.12 |
| A | c | 0.19 |
| B | a | 0.15 |
| B | b | 0.2 |
| B | c | 0.09 |
| C | a | 0.39 |
| C | b | 0.15 |
| C | c | 0.01 |

and I would like to get the following

| ID | freq_a | freq_b | freq_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.1 | 0.12 | 0.19 |
| B | 0.15 | 0.2 | 0.09 |
| C | 0.39 | 0.15 | 0.01 |

Any ideas how to easily do this?

Answer (score 0):

using pivot:

```
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='value', values='freq').add_prefix('freq_').reset_index()
```

output:

```
>>
value ID  freq_a  freq_b  freq_c
0      A    0.10    0.12    0.19
1      B    0.15    0.20    0.09
2      C    0.39    0.15    0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
out = df.pivot_table('freq', 'ID', 'value').add_prefix('freq_') \
        .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
  ID  freq_a  freq_b  freq_c
0  A    0.10    0.12    0.19
1  B    0.15    0.20    0.09
2  C    0.39    0.15    0.01
```